# Looking for a pattern in a list

Tags: python, performance

I've created this function that looks for sequences in a list. If `[1,2,3]` exists, it will print `True`. I've tested the code and it works fine.

```
def looking_patt(pattern,cursor,found):
    big_s = []
    for i in range(1,101):
        if i % 10 == 0:
            big_s.extend([1,2,3])
        else:
            big_s.append(i)
    # check control
    print(big_s)

    for i in big_s:
        if i == pattern[cursor]:
            cursor += 1
            if cursor == len(pattern):
                found.append(pattern)
                print(found)
                cursor = 0
        else:
            cursor = 0  

    print(len(found) > 0)
```

Part of the script (the `for i in big_s:`) has been taken from an answer in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10106901/elegant-find-sub-list-in-list).

How can it be improved?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess that the first part of your code is just to initialize the sample data.

Then here are a few things:

- Separate initialization and main loop. I know this is just an exercise, but always doing it will help you keep the mindset.
- If you only need to count something, just count it. Don't keep track of everything.
- If you only need to check the existence of something, use a boolean value and return as soon as you've found it. Adding elements to a list so that at the end you can count them and return a boolean based on the count is definitely not an efficient way to do it.
- What you call `cursor` is actually an integer, not an object, so the name `index` may be more appropriate
- If you want to give the chance to start searching from a specific index, you may also want to have a default value for that parameter (0 looks like a good choice)
- You don't need the third parameter, that's what you are going to return

This is my attempt at it:

```
big_s = []

def init_big_s():
    for i in range(1,101):
        if i % 10 == 0:
            big_s.extend([1,2,3])
        else:
            big_s.append(i)

def looking_patt(pattern, index=0):
    for i in big_s:
        if i == pattern[index]:
            index += 1
            if index == len(pattern):
                return True
        else:
            index = 0  
    return False

init_big_s()
print looking_patt([1, 2, 3])
```

Comment: Hi @chatterone, thanks for your feedback. ok for separating the functionS, this is what I did initially but I said to myself `Hey why not put everything into one umbrella?` Can you explain a bit more `If you only need to check the existence of something, use a boolean value and return as soon as you've found it. Adding elements to a list so that at the end you can count them and return a boolean based on the count is definitely not an efficient way to do it.` this part?

Comment: @AndyK if you don't need to compute something, just don't do it :-) If the purpose of the function was to return the patterns that you found, you may have had a point. But if all you need is a check that the pattern exists, just return True as soon as the first pattern is found, no need to save the elements.